# Wrong details from Google searches

Tags: google, google-search-console, search

I manage a university website. and when you try to search for "top universities in the Philippines" it will show the wrong logo and the wrong website. but it shows the name of our university and the address on the right side panel as well as our description.
Can you guys give me any hints on what am I doing wrong? I Added alt tags from our logo and asked for a reindex on search console. But its still showing the wrong details.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: If you search for "Top universities in the philippines", on the 18th spot. you will see our name "University of perpetual help system DALTA, Las pinas", But the logo shown there is from University of perpetual help system LAGUNA, and the right logo for us is the the one the right side (Maroon), and when you clicked the logo. It will show the website of UPHSL.edu.ph which should have been perpetualdalta.edu.ph since the one on the right panel is University of perpetual help system DALTA, not LAGUNA.

[image: Example:]

Comment: There are no details enough for us to even guess. Can you provide a screen shot?? Or a search query and university name (or hint)? Otherwise, there is nothing actionable here. Cheers!!

Comment: Thanks for the update. Are you hitting google.com? I am not seeing what you are seeing. I will keep poking around.

Comment: Are these completely different schools? Two different websites? It appears that there is some confusion in the knowledge graph. Perhaps some overlap of some sort. I would want to look at schema.org mark-up and branding.

Comment: Mods: at first blush, this question appears to be about one particular website. After poking around, it appears to be something else. Perhaps confusion on the search end.

Comment: Both are different universities, Perpetualdalta.edu.ph and uphsl.edu.ph with different managements, the one i am ranking is perpetualdalta.edu.ph. a month ago, Google.com was displaying exactly our logo and other details but since an attack (hack) in our website (resolved already), Google is now displaying the results I raised on my question.

Comment: I added an image. Is this what you are talking about?

Comment: This is a good question because it illustrates one example of how Google can return the wrong thing and how specifically a site should sculpt it's reputation on it's site. Reputation in search is key. Cheers!!

Comment: For what it worth, I love the Philippines and it's people. I have been there 18 times for as much as a month at a time. If I had a choice, I might not have come back home and built a life in the most beautiful country I have ever seen! Cheers!!

Comment: Google has been nuts lately. between them trying to force the new adsense on developers and forcing people to upgrade their browsers to see the current youtube. Next thing you know, their search engine might end up being a complete mess in one year unless they listen to the poor little guys like us developers. I'm sorry, but I'm in a ranting mood. Nevertheless, you did ask a good question OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay. This is actually simple.

This is what I am seeing.

[image: Wrong image as indicated.]

This image comes from http://www.pinoyexchange.com/, more specifically, http://www.pinoyexchange.com/forums/showthread.php?t=714586 where this image exists http://i60.tinypic.com/2zyhetx.png.

[image: Same or similar image.]

While this answer and your question do not line-up exactly, this is probably a good example of what is going on. This image is coming up for searches based upon the search query. Other search queries will likely have different results.

### So what do you do about it?

The primary problem is that image search is different from textual search.

Two things.

1] Use the image prominently on the website such as in the header or footer taking full advantage of the img tag alt text. I suggest taking your present logo and splitting it to separate the actual logo from the text and using how you want to be known in search as the alt text.

2] Is to use schema.org mark-up for your school and be sure to use "logo" found here: https://schema.org/logo. Of course you should use the logo image without the attached text. This should be on your Contact Page and/or About Page and/or in the header or footer. I would suggest taking full advantage of schema mark-up. The advantage here is that schema mark-up fuels the knowledge graph.

For what it is worth, an image search using your search phrase does show the correct image first. The bad news is that the image is on Wikipedia. The good news is that the image is on Wikipedia. [insert cheese eating grin here] Wikipedia is used directly in the knowledge graph. That is the good news. Now you simply have to create positive image search results that returns your logo for your site more consistently than the pinoyexchange.com site and possibly even Wikipedia.

### What is often missed.

Site owners often forget about site reputation which is not just short-circuiting negative results. It can also be about sculpting search results with positive results that return a user to their site. This is the nature of SEO. Images are often ignored. So is the knowledge graph. Optimizing for image search and properly using schema mark-up are significant tools for any site and positive search results.

Keep in mind that you will need to explore how your site appears for a variety of search queries and determine which ones are most important for your users. Not you. From there, you can sculpt your sites presentation to optimize toward these searches. Also keep in mind, that search is not a perfect world and some compromises may be needed toward how people search the most.

Comment: This is exactly what I did, Had to wait a little longer for me to see the result. And now its all good. Thanks

Comment: @FrustratedDeveloper Good!! Thanks for the feed back. We rarely get such good news! Thank you for sharing that. Cheers!!