# Company profile not loading in Google search after disabling Google+ and implementing alternatives

Tags: google-search-console, google-search

I had setup a google plus account for the organization and the profile was appearing in google. But for some reason I decided not to put google plus profile, so I disabled it and I found the alternative for the same by doing as in the link https://9clouds.com/blog/4-steps-add-social-media-links-google-results/ . I followed every step exactly how it is in the link.
The added code is as follows:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
  { 
     "@context" : "http://schema.org",
     "@type" : "Organization",
     "name" : "Organization name",
     "url" : "siteurl",
     "logo": "image link",
     "sameAs" : [ 
       "https://www.facebook.com/Org_name",
       "https://twitter.com/Org_name",
       "https://plus.google.com/+Org_name",
       "https://www.linkedin.com/company/Org-name",
       "http://www.youtube.com/c/Org_name"
     ]
   }
 </script>
```

Now my problem is after making the changes the profile is not showing in the google search and after some days, google plus profile again started displaying in search results. When I check, the settings I disabled were again reset automatically and google plus profile is again shown.

There are no other Google plus managers for my organization and I only manage them. So there is no possibility of someone changing the setting to appear it again.

I am not able to pinpoint either problems (G+ account profile re-appearing and the above code not working).
I want to completely remove Google plus profile in search results and I want to show my own profile from my website as it comes for IBM, Microsoft etc.

(The reason I do not want Google plus profile is, it shows unrelated photos and also it shows other information which is not required)
Please help to solve the problem.

Is there any other way for getting the profile in the google search page apart from google+ page?

Comment: I cannot comment on how or why G+ was reset. Not sure anyone can. I can tell you that G+ still offers opportunities you cannot get anywhere else. For example, G+ feeds the knowledge graph directly. But then again, so does Wikipedia. So if you do decide to disable G+, you will see a drop in some options that people covet. However, some of that can be recovered with a Wikipedia page. Be that as it may, I would be working on why some information from G+ appeared differently. See: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/101782/wrong-details-from-google-searches It may be somewhat similar.

Comment: You will see that a simple search for *ibm* returns a card from the knowledge graph that takes information directly from Wikipedia. Same with Microsoft. Granted, both cards do take information from a variety of sources. G+ allows for reviews, maps, image search, etc. which should be beneficial especially for a smaller or new company. Cheers!!